# Line spacing in table without using booktabs

Tags: tables, vertical-alignment, fractions, vertical-spacing

I'm having a problem with a table I'm trying to do. This is the code I currently have :

```
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper,french]{extarticle}
\usepackage[margin=.75in]{geometry}

\renewcommand{\l}{\left}
\renewcommand{\r}{\right}
\renewcommand{\d}{\displaystyle}
\newcommand{\virg}{\:,\:}

\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{2}
\usepackage{multirow}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{cc|c|c|}
\cline{3-4}
 &  & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{Individu 1} \\ \cline{3-4} 
 &  & Colombe & Faucun \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\multirow{2}{*}{Individu 2}} & Colombe & \(\d\l(\frac{g}{2} \virg \frac{g}{2}\r)\) & \((g \virg 0)\) \\ \cline{2-4} 
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{} & Faucon  & \((0 \virg g)\) & \(\d\l(\frac{g-c}{2} \virg \frac{g-c}{2}\r)\) \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

The result I want is a table which contains fractions. But the lines are way too narrow and the fractions touch the line on top and on the bottom of them.

I tried to ajust the arraystretch to 2 (using `\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{2}`) but this messes up the vertical centering of the text in the cell, as it only adds space on top of the text. Is there any way to fix this issue?

Note : I cannot use booktabs because the table I'm drawing must have vertical lines. It should look like this:

[image]

Made in word, the font and the spacing is not exactly what I needAnd this is what I currently have :
[image]

(Made in word, the font and the spacing is not exactly what I need)

Comment: Just out of idle curiosity, is this 2x2 matrix some version of the Prisoners' Dilemma payoff problem?

Comment: Yeah! I had a really hard time trying to make it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do yourself a favor and *don't* redefine `\l`, `\r` and `\d`. You may find them handy shortcuts, but you'll be in great trouble in case the standard meaning of those commands (which have to do with accents) is needed.

The setting of the widths could be made based on the width of the wide pair, but it just take a moment to guess the good one.

```
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper,french]{extarticle}
\usepackage[margin=.75in]{geometry}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{multirow,array}

%\usepackage{xparse} % not needed with LaTeX 2020-10-01 or later

\NewDocumentCommand{\pair}{s O{} >{\SplitArgument{1}{,}}m }{%
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}
    {\left(\makepair#3\right)}
    {\mathopen{#2(}\makepair#3\mathclose{#2)}}%
}
\NewDocumentCommand{\makepair}{ m m }{%
  #1\mspace{4mu}{,}\mspace{4mu}#2%
}

\newcommand{\adj}[1]{\ensuremath{\vphantom{#1|}}\ignorespaces}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|w{c}{7em}|w{c}{7em}|}
\cline{3-4}
\multicolumn{2}{c|}{\adj{\Big}} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{Individu 1} \\
\cline{3-4} 
\multicolumn{2}{c|}{\adj{\Big}} & Colombe & Faucon \\
\hline
\multirow{3}{*}{Individu 2}
& \adj{\bigg} Colombe & \(\pair[\Big]{\dfrac{g}{2},\dfrac{g}{2}}\) & \(\pair{g,0}\) \\
\cline{2-4}
& \adj{\bigg} Faucon  & \(\pair{0,g}\) & \(\pair[\Big]{\dfrac{g-c}{2},\dfrac{g-c}{2}}\) \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

What's `\adj{\Big}`? I adds a strut like `\Big|`. For the rows with the big pairs, I used `\adj{\bigg}`, because the parentheses are already `\Big`.

Note also the syntax `\pair{x,y}` which is easier than `(x\virg y)`.

Why not using `\left` and `\right`? Look closely at your output and you'll notice that the sizes of the large parentheses in the top row and in the bottom row are *different*. The reason is the presence of the minus sign in the bottom row, believe it or not.

[image]

---

A different suggestion.

```
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper,french]{extarticle}
\usepackage[margin=.75in]{geometry}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{booktabs,array}

%\usepackage{xparse} % not needed with LaTeX 2020-10-01 or later

\NewDocumentCommand{\pair}{s O{} >{\SplitArgument{1}{,}}m }{%
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}
    {\left(\makepair#3\right)}
    {\mathopen{#2(}\makepair#3\mathclose{#2)}}%
}
\NewDocumentCommand{\makepair}{ m m }{%
  #1\mspace{4mu}{,}\mspace{4mu}#2%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{c w{c}{7em} w{c}{7em}}
\toprule
Individu 2 & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Individu 1} \\
\cmidrule(lr){2-3}
& Colombe & Faucon \\
\midrule
Colombe & \(\pair[\Big]{\dfrac{g}{2},\dfrac{g}{2}}\) & \(\pair{g,0}\) \\
\addlinespace
Faucon  & \(\pair{0,g}\) & \(\pair[\Big]{\dfrac{g-c}{2},\dfrac{g-c}{2}}\) \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1. I think the (correct) French spelling of "falcon" is "faucon", not "faucun", though... :-)

Comment: @Mico I just copied from the OP's code. I'll fix.

Comment: Sorry I had a spelling mistake oups!

Comment: I keep getting the error ```Illegal pream-token (w): `c' used.``` for ```\begin{tabular}{|c|c|w{c}{7em}|w{c}{7em}|}```. How would I fix this? (for first solution)

Comment: I went for the ```booktabs``` solution. This makes for a very nice table and will give better reading results for big results. Thank you very much!

Comment: @AlexandreSimard Update your TeX system: the `w` column type has been in `array` for at least a year.

Answer (score 4):

Like this?

[image]

One way is use of the instruction `\makegapedcells` defined in the `makecell` package, which add vertical space above/below cells' contents:

```
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper,french]{extarticle}
\usepackage[margin=.75in]{geometry}

\renewcommand{\l}{\left}
\renewcommand{\r}{\right}
\renewcommand{\d}{\displaystyle}
\newcommand{\virg}{\:,\:}

\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{2}
\usepackage{makecell, multirow}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\setcellgapes{5pt}
\makegapedcells
\begin{tabular}{cc|c|c|}
\cline{3-4}
 &  & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{Individu 1} \\ \cline{3-4}
 &  & Colombe & Faucun \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\multirow{2}{*}{Individu 2}} & Colombe & \(\d\l(\frac{g}{2} \virg \frac{g}{2}\r)\) & \((g \virg 0)\) \\ \cline{2-4}
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{} & Faucon  & \((0 \virg g)\) & \(\d\l(\frac{g-c}{2} \virg \frac{g-c}{2}\r)\) \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

**Addendum:**
Considering @Mico comment, i make the following changes to above solution:

- Use `amsmath` package for command`\dfrac`, by which is replaced your definition to use `\displaystyle` at fractions.
- remove definition for `\l`, `\r`, it is better to write `\left` and `right`.
- to make third and fourth rows aequal height, the `\vphantom{-}` is added to the fraction in third rows. With its, the fracions height in bot rows become equal height.

New MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper,french]{extarticle}
\usepackage[margin=.75in]{geometry}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\newcommand{\virg}{\:,\:}
\usepackage{makecell, multirow}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\setcellgapes{5pt}
\makegapedcells
\begin{tabular}{cc|c|c|}
    \cline{3-4}
    &           & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{Individu 1}   \\ \cline{3-4}
    &           & Colombe   & Faucun \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\multirow{4}{*}{Individu 2}} 
    & Colombe   & \(\left(\dfrac{g}{2}\virg\dfrac{g\vphantom{-}}{2}\right)\) 
                            & \((g\virg0)\)         \\ \cline{2-4}
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{} 
    & Faucon    & \((0\ ,\ g)\) 
                            & \(\left(\dfrac{g-c}{2}\virg\dfrac{g-c}{2}\right)\) \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is perfect for what I want! Thank you

Comment: Can you produce a solution in which the tall parentheses in rows 3 and 4 have the same height?

Comment: @Mico, that is challenge. I wonder, why fractions n these rows haven't the same height. Apparently it depends if in it is present math operator. If I add it in `\vphantom` command, then rows have the same height. I will add this to answer asap.

Comment: @Mico, see edited answer. I believe that now table is nicer.

Comment: I just changed the ```\left(``` and ```\right)``` to ```\bigg(``` and ```\bigg)``` which fixed the problem of the height. It's easier than the ```\vphantom```

Comment: @AlexandreSimard, your solution is even better ...

Answer (score 2):

I think the tool of choice for this problem is `cellspace` which ensures a *minimal* vertical spacing at the top and bottom of cells in columns with specifier prefixed with the letter `S` (or `C` if you load `siunitx`):

```
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper,french]{extarticle}
\usepackage[margin=.75in]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath} 
\usepackage{cellspace}
\setlength{\cellspacetoplimit}{5pt}
\setlength{\cellspacebottomlimit}{5pt}
\renewcommand{\l}{\left}
\renewcommand{\r}{\right}
\renewcommand{\d}{\displaystyle}
\newcommand{\virg}{\:,\:}

\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{2}
\usepackage{multirow}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{cc|Sc|Sc|}
\cline{3-4}
 & & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{Individu 1} \\ \cline{3-4}
 & & Colombe & Faucun \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\multirow{2}{*}{Individu 2}} & Colombe & \(\Bigl(\dfrac{g}{2} \virg \dfrac{g}{2}\Bigr)\) & \((g \virg 0)\) \\ \cline{2-4}
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{} & Faucon & \((0 \virg g)\) & \(\Bigl(\dfrac{g-c}{2} \virg \dfrac{g-c}{2}\Bigr)\) \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Can you produce a solution in which the tall parentheses in rows 3 and 4 have the same height?

Comment: Oh! yes, of course I didn't think of modifying the shortcut in the O.P.

Comment: While you're at it, do please fix the spelling of "faucun"...

Comment: I was my intention to ask the O.P.  what a ‘faucun’ is. I hesitated between  ‘un faux-cul’ and ‘un vrai con’, if you speak french…

Comment: Oui, bien sur que je parle français -- je suis valaisan (du Haut Valais). :-)

Comment: Ah! le fendant…

Comment: Désolé pour l'erreur de frappe!

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your requirements correctly, the first `tabular` solution below should work, as all four columns have the exact same widths and all four rows have the same heights. However, I think that the second `tabular` solution below looks (even) better.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper,french]{extarticle}
\usepackage[margin=.75in]{geometry}
\usepackage{multirow,array,babel,amsmath}
\newcommand\myfrac{\Bigl( \frac{g-c}{2}, \frac{g-c}{2} \Bigr)}
\newlength\mylen
\settowidth\mylen{$\displaystyle\myfrac$}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{$\displaystyle}w{c}{\mylen}<{$}}
\newcommand\tallstrut{\vphantom{\biggl|}} % typographic struts
\newcommand\shortstrut{\smash[b]{\vphantom{\Bigl|}}}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\centering

\begin{tabular}{|w{c}{\mylen}|w{c}{\mylen}|C|C|}
\cline{3-4}
\multicolumn{1}{c}{} & & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{Individu 1$\tallstrut$} \\
\cline{3-4}
\multicolumn{1}{c}{} & & $Colombe$\tallstrut & $Faucon$\tallstrut \\
\hline
\multirow{3}{*}{Individu 2} 
  & Colombe & \Bigl( \frac{g}{2}, \frac{g}{2} \Bigr)\tallstrut & (g,0) \\
\cline{2-4}
  & Faucon & (0,g)\tallstrut & \myfrac \\
\hline
\end{tabular}

\bigskip\bigskip

\begin{tabular}{|c|c|C|C|}
\cline{3-4}
\multicolumn{1}{c}{} & & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{Individu 1$\shortstrut$} \\
\cline{3-4}
\multicolumn{1}{c}{} & & $Colombe$\shortstrut & $Faucon$ \\
\hline
\multirow{3}{*}{Individu 2} 
  & Colombe & \Bigl( \frac{g}{2}, \frac{g}{2} \Bigr)\tallstrut & (g,0) \\
\cline{2-4}
  & Faucon & (0,g)\tallstrut & \myfrac \\
\hline
\end{tabular}

\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: The second one is indeed what I wanted, sorry for bad instructions!